# Is there a way to call a webservice whose asmx file is deleted?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, asmx

I have an IIS server which runs an app containing several web services. There is a `.asmx` file for each web service. For some reason, I have to restrict the access to the web services so i have deleted some of the `asmx` files.
Now my question is, can a client still call all the web services even without the asmx file? (I haven't changed the code, just deleted the `.asmx` files)

Comment: What happens if you delete one and try to call the webservice?

Comment: after deleting it, i get 404 error not found. can i be completely sure no one can call it? is it safe?

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot use the code behind without an asmx file.** IIS does not know which class to use for implementation of the service.

You need to recreate the asmx file. Their content is quite simple. It is just a single line like

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="ASWBW_002.asmx.cs" Class="P0300_GUI.Interfaces.ASWBW_002" %>
```

All you need is the name of the implementing class including the namespace. Usually this is the File name and parts of the path.

Answer (score 0):

The ASMX file serves as a binding between the contract and its implementation. The client upon hitting the ASMX, the corresponding IIS handler invokes the underlying class to get the methods to fire. Removing this binding renders the service unavailable.

For a proper solution, follow these:-
In general, you need to identify who all clients can access your web service. Once done, you need a mechanism to provide them the WSDL file so they can generate their proxy classes.

Once done, disable the WSDL discovery using steps [Disable Service Help Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tyf2t8t(v=vs.100).aspx) by removing the documentation protocol. Post this, no client can get the WSDL and hence any updates (even existing verified clients)

If you want to implement selective availability, you have to incorporate SOAP Header based security using WS-Security policy.

Please note that WS-* and ASMX technologies are now considered as legacy and are not supported by Microsoft. Please upgrade to WCF/WebAPI instead.